# How to edit files on Netsuite SuiteCommerce Advanced?

Tags: eclipse, netsuite, suitecommerce

I recently given a task to work on Netsuite SuiteCommerce Advanced. The site have bunch of other microsites configured with it. I have zero knowledge about it as in last week. I tried to familiar myself with the system. For example, when I try to edit the logo under SuiteCommerce > Global > Templates > header > macros > logo_macro.txt, I saw in the code that it retrieves the value from config: application.getConfig("logoUrl") and application.getConfig("siteSettings.displayname") but I don't know where's that value is stored? and how about if I want to edit the file, how can I FTP to the file cabinet?

I know where to change the file (from the File Cabinet web interface) and code but want to make sure that it doesn't affect other sites so there could be a config for each microstore as it seems that each file can be shared among other microsites (if I go to file cabinet, hit edit, then it will show me different URL for the microsites). I also read their documentation regarding Netsuite IDE, so I downloaded Eclipse and install NetSuite extension but it seems that it's only for SuiteScript project or ssp application. Once I have Eclipse open, I don't know how to edit the file and upload it to Netsuite.

I search the web for any tutorial regarding netsuite and suitecommerce advanced in general and surprisingly there's very little information about it. Almost no tutorial exists and if you want to learn about it, you need to attend a class/workshop for a fee. I even look on Amazon to find a book to read/learn and once again, it came up empty. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to NetSuite where many start blind like you are so don't feel bad. Your statement about virtually zero documentation about NetSuite is accurate so expect it to take some time. When developers are earning strong six figures doing something you can usually assume learning it doesn't come overnight.

If you are a JavasScript expert, you may pick it up faster but there are so many idiosyncrasies in NetSuite. In a few months you'll know what I'm talking about.

**Finding where application.getConfig comes from:**

That is most likely a JavaScript function defined globally at application. Almost all code in NetSuite is JavaScript and it can run on the server or client. If I'm correct than you'll need to find the .js file. One way is to manually scan through the File Cabinet and look into any file that looks possible.

The better way to find it is download all of the SuiteScript to your local machine so you can search it. One way to do that is using the NetSuite IDE and Eclipse or the File Cabinet.

**To download from the file cabinet:**

Go to Documents > Files > File Cabinet.
Navigate to the file or folder you want to download.
Click Download next to the file or folder.
When you download a folder, all of the files and subfolders are downloaded in a ZIP file to maintain the folder hierarchy.

**About changing files will it affect micro-sites**

I can't tell you if changing a file will affect micro sites that sounds specific to your company. I'd be inclined to think that they have functions that exist across sites so be careful. One way you might try is see if the JavaScript function is available in each of the sites.

**Learning NetSuite**

There is only one good way that I've found. Log into NetSuite, click the Help and a window will open. Or pay ten thousand for a high level overview training. Seriously the NetSuite help is extensive and you must spend much time in there before making changes. You can find blogs about NetSuite but most are trying to sell their consulting services. I started NetSuiteGo in hopes of sharing the missing code examples, etc. and welcome guest articles if anyone wants to pay-it-forward. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Very true described the things. NetSuite making money through services they are offering for their products.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to set up a local environment than to edit raw files from within the File Cabinet. If you had an outside development team that built the site for you, you should ask them for their customized files, otherwise you won't be able to test the site as it is in its current state.